# Many To Many extra column merge insert new child

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm having trouble getting my merge to cascade down when there are new child objects. I have a parent object (A) with a set of child objects

Class A:

```
public class A implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_A")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    private List<AB> ab= new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Class B:

```
public class B implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_B")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

}
```

Class AB:

```
public class AB implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_A")
        private A a;

        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_B")
        private B b;

        @Column(name = "INFO")
        private String info;

    }
```

Insertion works with this code.

```
A a = new A();
B b = bRepository.findById(1L);
Ab ab = new Ab(a,b,"");
a.setAB(ab);
aRepository.save(a);
```

The update works if the child ab exists in the database

```
A a = aRepository.findById(1L);
B b = bRepository.findById(1L);
Ab ab = new Ab(a,b,"");
a.setAB(ab);
aRepository.save(a);
```

If the child not exist, I receive this error

> "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","message":"ORA-01400: impossible d'insérer NULL dans (\"DB\".\"AB\".\"B\")\n"

Comment: try `a.getAB().put(ab); aRepository.save(a);`

Comment: ab is a list type, i tried by  `a.getAB().add(ab);aRepository.save(a);` but always the same error is present :(